# Send File using jQuery In Post method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im not able to read file in jquery by using this code

//Html Code

```
< input type="file" id="UploadedImage" name="UploadedImage" accept="image/*">
```

//JS code

```
  var file_data = $("#UploadedImage").prop("files")[0];  
  var form_data = new FormData();        

            form_data.append("fileData", file_data);

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:Drupal.settings.basePath + 'KycCallBack',
                    data:
                    {
                        id:"SaveKYC",
                        UploadedImage:form_data,

                    },
                    success:function(data)
                    {

                        jQuery(".ajaxLoading").hide();
```

// I want to read as like this in php in my API

```
    $UploadedImage = $_FILES["UploadedImage"]["name"];  
    $target_dir = "sites/all/modules/vestigepos/vestigepos/KYCImages/";
    $target_dir = $target_dir . basename( $_FILES["UploadedImage"]["name"]);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["UploadedImage"]["tmp_name"],     $target_dir)) {
                    echo "File Uploaded ";
                    }
```

Comment: Have you checked if the file is being transferred, using the browser debug tools? That'll allow you to narrow down whether it's a PHP or JavaScript problem.

Comment: yes when i print "file_data"   
File {name: "pan.jpg", lastModified: 1443415750000, lastModifiedDate: Mon Sep 28 2015 10:19:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 176964…}

Comment: in console  it prints

Comment: file_data 
File {name: "pan.jpg", lastModified: 1443415750000, lastModifiedDate: Mon Sep 28 2015 10:19:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 176964…}

Comment: That's the current value of `file_data`, but that doesn't mean that's being uploaded. Use a network trace to capture the actual request content that's being sent to the server to confirm. That will allow you to simplify your question into just a JavaScript problem or just a PHP problem.

Comment: or dump the file var to console in the php side